# Casting a const reference to a const pointer to a const

Tags: c++, stl, constants

I am building an STL list.  I made a decorator class (`MyList`) that is a list of a special class (`ProtectMe`).  I want all of the items of the list to be const.  So here's what I made:

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class ProtectMe{
private:
    int data_;
public:
    ProtectMe(int data):data_(data){
    }

    int data() const{return data_;}
};

class MyList{
private:
    //A list of constant pointers to constant ProtectMes.
    list<const ProtectMe* const> guts_;
public:
    void add(const ProtectMe& data){
        guts_.push_front(&data);
    }
};
```

I get the following compile error:

```
error: ‘const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::address(const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = const ProtectMe* const]’ cannot be overloaded
```

I'm still scratching my head trying to decode where I went wrong.  Why doesn't this code compile?  What should I change?

Comment: `guts_.push_front(const &data);` Why keyword const in brackets ? Why do you wish list elements to be of pointers type ?

Comment: @Mahesh:  No good reason.  Just trying to make it compile.  It obviously didn't help.  I'll remove it...

Comment: Why not just list<ProtectMe> are you deriving from ProtectMe somewhere else???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value_type` of standard containers must be `CopyInsertable` (or `MoveInsertable`) in order for the `push_front` to work. The value type of `list<const ProtectMe* const>` is constant, so it's not `CopyInsertable`.

† `CopyInsertable` means that

```
allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v);
```

is well defined where `p` is a pointer to `value_type`, which by default calls placement new on p and thus requires it to be a non-const pointer.

Comment: Interesting..So, how would I have a list of const objects?  As the name implies, I want ProtectMe to be read-only.  Imagine there is a non-const method in ProtectMe...

Comment: @User1: `list<const ProtectMe*>` is enough, you won't be able to modify the pointed `ProtectMe`s.